# Three prove/disprove question in calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, convergence-divergence

1) $f:(0,\infty$)$\to\Bbb R$ Continuously differentiable function which maintain 
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \ xf'(x)$=1 than $ \lim_{x\to\infty} \ f(x)$=$\infty$.

2) For every $n$,  $a_n>0$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \ na_n = 1$ than $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ diverges.

3) For every $n$,  $a_n>0$  and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $  converges than  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \max (a_n,a_{n+1}) $ converges.

For the first question I think its correct since I tried every function imaginable I could think of, but I could not prove it.

For the second question with the condition $a_n>0$ I tried to use comparison theories but it did not help (assumed it is not correct but did not get to a contradiction)  so I figure it is false, but I could not find a counterexample with the condition $a_n>0$.

For the third I figure its false with a function similar to $\sin(n)$(not monotonic function in general) but again the condition $a_n>0$ sabotages it.

Hints will be appreciated (if there is a site for counterexamples I will be glad).

Comment: Could you add your efforts in there too, for each point?

Comment: @Kevin yes i will

Comment: That's great, you should get a better repsone from posters now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer:

1) True. Since $\lim_{x\to \infty }xf'(x)=1,$ there exists $\alpha >0$ such that

$$xf'(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}\; \forall\; x\geq \alpha.$$ In particular,

$$f'(x)\geq \frac{1}{2x}\; \forall\; x\geq \alpha.$$Now, if $x\geq \alpha,$ we have

$$f(x)=f(\alpha)+\int_\alpha^x f'(t)dt\geq f(\alpha)+\int_\alpha^x \frac{1}{2x}dt$$ 
$$=f(\alpha)+ \frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{x}{\alpha})\to \infty.$$

2) False. Define $a_n= \frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is not a perfect square and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is a perfect square. Then $\limsup na_n=1$ and $\sum a_n$ converges. On the other hand, if instead of  $\limsup na_n=1$ you impose  $\lim na_n=1,$ then the statement is true. You prove this as follows:

Since $\lim na_n=1,$ then exists $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$ we have

$$na_n\geq \frac{1}{2}, \textrm{ or equivalently, } a_n\geq \frac{1}{2n}.$$ The result follows from the fact that the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

3) True. It suffices to prove that the sequence of partial sums,

$$S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n \max(a_k,a_{k+1})$$ is Cauchy. Since $\sum a_k$ converges, the sequence $$s_n= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$ is Cauchy. Now take any $\epsilon >0.$ Then, there exists $n_0$ such that $n\geq m\geq n_0$ implies

$$s_n-s_m= \sum_{k=m}^n a_k \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ Hence, for $n\geq m\geq n_0$ we also have 
$$S_n-S_m= \sum_{k=m}^n \max(a_k,a_{k+1})\leq 2 \sum_{k=m}^{n+1} a_k \leq 2\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$ This means that $S_n$ is cauchy and hence convergent.

Hope this helps

Comment: its $\lim_{x\to\infty} \ xf'(x)$=1 not $\lim_{x\to\infty} \ xf'(x)$=$\infty$ but it still holds , thank you.

Comment: yes, it was mistype. Already fixed

Comment: For the third one, we can just use the fact that $\max(a_n,a_{n+1})\leq a_n+a_{n+1}$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Absolutely!! I over- thought this. Thanks for the comment!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Here I will just make a comment: Intuitively $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf'(x) = 1$ means that $f' \approx \frac1x$ for large $x$, so $f(x) \approx \ln x + C$ which grows to infinity as $x \to \infty$.
2. Take $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $n a_n = (-1)^n$ so $\limsup n a_n = +1$. The series $\sum_n a_n$ is alternating with $|a_n| \to 0$ and is therefore convergent.
3. Set $b_n = a_n$ if $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$ and $=0$ otherwise. Set $c_n = a_{n+1}$ if $a_n < a_{n+1}$ and $=0$ otherwise. Then $0 \leq b_n \leq a_n$, $0 \leq c_n \leq a_{n+1}$ and $b_n+c_n = \max(a_n, a_{n+1})$. This implies that $0 \leq \sum b_n \leq \sum a_n < \infty$ and $0 \leq \sum c_n \leq \sum a_{n+1} < \infty$ so
   $$\sum \max(a_n, a_{n+1}) = \sum (b_n+c_n) = \sum b_n + \sum c_n < \infty.$$
   The splitting of the sum is okay when we only have non-negative terms.

Comment: The second answer does not apply since it suppose to be positive series for every n.

Comment: Ah, how could I miss that?